# Align vertices with curvature of another object

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am new to Blender, and I'm currently trying to align vertices of one object to the curvature of another object.

[image]

[image]

I can't use <kbd>S</kbd>, then some axis and then <kbd>0</kbd>, since both objects will (in the end) have a circular shape.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to use a curve modifier?

Comment: No, but how would I do it with a curve modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Shrinkwrap Modifier.

You can read about it in the [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) or watch this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lElT3_mP2Fg)